# How to remake a request when the page reload Flutter / GetX

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, obs

I'm making a flutter App for a project in my School and I have a problem. I have a page where there are widgets representing categories of articles and when a category is clicked a page with articles from that category is displayed. The problem is that once a category is called, the articles in that category remain the same despite the category change.
When the page is called, a controller is created that will execute the query that retrieves the items in the category.

How can I get this controller to remind me every time the page is loaded?

Category page code :

```
class ProduceCategoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = "/produceByCategorie";

  @override
  State<ProduceCategoryScreen> createState() => _ProduceCategoryScreenState();
}

class _ProduceCategoryScreenState extends State<ProduceCategoryScreen> {
  static int gridColumn = 1;

  static ArticleByCategoryController articleController =
      Get.put(ArticleByCategoryController());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Produitss"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'Green Tomato',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 32,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    switch (gridColumn) {
                      case 1:
                        setState(() {
                          gridColumn = 2;
                        });

                        break;
                      case 2:
                        setState(() {
                          gridColumn = 1;
                        });
                        break;
                      default:
                    }
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.grid_view),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Obx(
              () {
                if (articleController.isLoading.value)
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                else
                  return AlignedGridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: gridColumn,
                    itemCount: articleController.articleList.length,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ProductTile(articleController.articleList[index]);
                    },
                  );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[The category widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCBR4.png)

[Category screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjZqu.png)

If you want more information you can send me a message on my discord : PascheK7#6324.

Comment: Not getting your question. kindly explain. Are you getting wrong articleDetail on Next page ? or you want resume method kind of mechanism when page comes back from Detail page to List page ?

Comment: @Dharmendra the first time I go in a category it work and after if I go in another category it show the first category.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing same list of data everytime when you execute below line.
"return ProductTile(articleController.articleList[index]);"

articleController.articleList : does this list contain only one category data ?
or it is contain category wise data.
e.g. : articleController.articleList[0] = category 1 list
articleController.articleList[1] = category 2 list
articleController.articleList[2] = category 3 list --> this way, it shouldn't make problem.

If articleList contain only one category data, then issue can happen that you get same data everytime. bcoz you are passing only index, but not category wise data.